Notification of near-exhaustion of apache children
The other day, I found a strange bug that others have confirmed.
In PHP, if one uses a header() statement and the first parameter begins with "HTTP/1.1 then after the script is executed, there's about a 3 second stall before the apache child opens up to new requests. This in turn makes the rest of the server slow because when all children are used up, no more requests can be served until some children become free. Yes I use apache in prefork mode with over 70 children total available.
What I want to know is if there's a way I can somehow setup the server (or apache itself) so I can receive an email when almost all of the children are used up. More like a warning to me so I can take action on the server to figure out what is hogging the children and to minimize waiting time when people want to access my website.

I don't use Prefork mode, but presumably it would be fairly trivial to write a script which checks every minute or so and counts the number of children.  If you do a ps waux | egrep 'apache|php|httpd' what does it output (once we know this, writing the script is easy.)


before the apache child opens up to new requests.

What does that mean?
If you mean available for another client to use, then its probably in Keepalive. Install/configure mod_status to get a better picture of what's happening.
If you have a Keepalive setting greater than 1 second you can probably reduce it to 1 without an adverse impact on performance (but increasing capacity).
I believe that sending a "Connection: Close" header from PHP will also free up the child almost immediately even if Keepalive has not expired, although I've not tested this myself.

so I can receive an email when almost all of the children are used up

That's a task for your monitoring system, but scripting this as cron job on MPM pre-fork would be trivial.

I did pinpoint the problem down to a BUG in PHP itself. Changing the HTTP status code using the PHP header statement reproduces the issue every time. It just would be nice if there was a way I could be emailed when I get another slowdown for any reason as per my question.

As far as I know, Apache doesn't have an email option for what you are requesting.
IMHO, you should look into tweaking your Apache configuration. You could either allocate more resources to it (more memory), increase the number of child processes, increase the max number of connections per child, or tweaking the KeepAlive settings.
From your problem description, I suspect the KeepAlive settings may the ones that will help you the most, particularly the KeepAliveTimeout. From the Apache manual:

Setting KeepAliveTimeout to a high value may cause performance
problems in heavily loaded servers. The higher the timeout, the more
server processes will be kept occupied waiting on connections with
idle clients.


I have tried all of those things.
